# jmh: Run benchmark concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency, jmh

I'm running a [jmh benchmark](http://java-performance.info/jmh/), but the invocations in each trial are occurring in serial. How can I make the invocations run concurrently?

Here's a summary of my code:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class FooBenchmark {
    @Param({"123456"})
    public int barId;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void run(Blackhole hole) {
        System.out.println("A"); // for proof that it's serial (see below)
        ...
        System.out.println("B"); // for proof that it's serial (see below)
    }   
}
```

This will print A and then B. Will never give two consecutive A's or B's.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to explicitly define the total amount of threads to use during your test, you need to annotate your test method (method annotated with `@Benchmark`) or your enclosing class with [`@Threads(numberOfThreads)`](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/master/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Threads.java) as next:

```
@Threads(10)
@Benchmark
public void run(Blackhole hole) {
```

In this example, `10` threads will execute the test method concurrently.

As reminder, here is part of the documentation that describes this annotation:

> Threads annotation provides the default number of threads to run.
>
> This annotation may be put at [`Benchmark`](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/master/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Benchmark.java) method to have effect
> on that method only, or at the enclosing class instance to have the effect
> over all [`Benchmark`](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/master/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Benchmark.java) methods in the class. This annotation may be
> overridden with the runtime options.

By default it will use only one thread.
If you use `@Threads(Threads.MAX)`, it will use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` threads.